# Setup SUBDIRS template failed in QtCreator

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator, qmake

The project is application(*.pro) with a static library(*.pro), so I am going to use `TEMPLATE = SUBDIRS` to manage it.

my workspace.pro

```
TEMPLATE = SUBDIRS
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

SUBDIRS += \
    MY_LIB \
    MY_APP1

MY_LIB.file=/Users/username/MYLIB/mylib.pro
MY_APP1.file=/Users/username/MYAPP/App1/App1.pro
```

The workspace.pro file is in `/Users/username/MYAPP/` directory.

When I tried to build it, QtCreator gave error 
    WARNING: Unable to generate output for: /Users/username/MYAPP/build-workspace_Qt_5_1_0_clang_64bit-Debug/Makefile [TEMPLATE SUBDIRS]

May I know how to solve it? and why it happen? Thanks.

Comment: I wanted to believe that QMAKE could parse for case-insensitivity... Faith is for people that don't RTFM.

Comment: In addition QT Creator autocompletes 's' to SUBDIRS in uppercase for some reason which makes this mistake very easy to make.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be `TEMPLATE = subdirs`, not SUBDIR.

Comment: He is not using SUBDIR.

Comment: oh,actually he is the first guy who point out my mistake. And I fixed it after that. I have read the document before I asked, just I did not notice the case sensitive issue. You answer is perfect, just I need to mark which person help me much, I also think it's fair for person who quickly give me great help, otherwise the last answer will always be the best one. I think it's typo on SUBDIR, you can edit his post, not big issue.

Answer (score 5):

Use `TEMPLATE = subdirs` instead of `TEMPLATE = SUBDIRS`, i.e. not upper case letters.

See the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-variable-reference.html#template) for further details. You should have written this instead:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

SUBDIRS += \
    MY_LIB \
    MY_APP1

MY_LIB.file=/Users/username/MYLIB/mylib.pro
MY_APP1.file=/Users/username/MYAPP/App1/App1.pro
```